# ios i want localize by stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, localization

i want localize stringWithFormat by this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Login %d in",2013];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@string, nil)
                                                        message:@"Message"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"sure", nil];
    [alertView show];
```

also i write this in Localizable.string:

```
"Login %d in" = "LOGIN %d IN";
```

and it doesn't work.can you help me?Thank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to localize the format string itself. Doing anything else doesn't make sense because the string can be practically anything when it's formatted (that's the purpose of format strings, after all). Just out of curiosity, haven't you seen things like

```
"%d seconds remaining" = "%d secondes restants";
"Hello, %@!" = "Bonjour, %@ !";
```

in the `Localizable.strings` file of applications you used yet?

```
NSString *localizedFmt = NSLocalizedString(@"Login %d in", nil);
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:localizedFmt, 2013],
    // etc...
];
```

---

**The Security Freak's Notice:** although this is **the** most common and easiest approach to localize formatted strings, it's not entirely safe.

An attacker can change the localized format string in the aforementioned `Localizable.strings` file of your app to something bogus, for example, to a string that contains more conversion specifiers than `stringWithFormat:` has arguments (or even mismatching specifiers - treating integers as pointers, anyone?), and then a stack smashing-based attack can be carried out against your application **- so beware of hackers.**

Comment: @Harry One suggestion. When working with localized format strings, it is best to use positional parameters just incase the order needs to be different in other languages. Of course this only applies when the format string has more than one format specifier.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, exactly. If we stick with the English-French example, one would have a hard time translating phrases with possessive clauses **and** maintaining word order.